# ASP.NET Handler (.ashx) with long Query String Parameters

Tags: asp.net, web-services, api, http

I want to know what is the best solution for creating ASP.NET HTTP Handler (.ashx) with long Query string parameters, as i have parameter like "description" which will be a long string which will make a problem in URL when access it by HTTP Request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want use `GET` method,you can't solved this problem,you can set it at [What is the maximum length of a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url) why.

you can change you .ASHX file accept the `POST` method.

```
<httpHandler>
  <add path="1.ashx" verb="post" type="" />
</httpHandler>
```

your server-side code like this :

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var stream = context.Request.InputStream;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            var text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

or alternative(based on your client-side how to send data)

```
   public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
       var text= context.Request.Form["text"];
    }
```

your client-side:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "1.ashx",
        data: { name: "John", time: "2pm" }
    });
</script>
```